# Is there any way to make mobile a server

Tags: python, react-native, python-requests

Hi I have a flask server written in python. I need it to be deployed to a mobile device.The reason for it is that I need the requests to be sent from the client. For that I need the flask app to run natively on the device of the client. I also can't write the requests from the client as I am dealing with httpOnly cookies that can't be seen in the js. I am writing the UI in react native, and I was wondering if there is any solution to my problem? Maybe my react native app will prompt the user to install the apk of the flask server on his device and then the client side will connect to that running server on his device?

Comment: So you think you need the Flask server as a proxy because React Native doesn't let you access httpOnly cookies? It might be possible anyway, because React Native does not run in a browser sandbox; see here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14076

Comment: it deosnt work trust me, I have tried everything. I cannot access the cookies I need from react native

Comment: also my flask server is not a proxy it is my main server

Comment: Why would you want a server to run on the same device as the client though? Either implement the required functionality client-side in the app itself, or put the server somewhere on the public internet.

Comment: I need the requests to be sent from the device. I am sending the request to an existent server that during authentication sends cookies that are httpOnly. I can't change that. That is the reason why this can't be implemented on the client side. 
I also can't put the logic of the requests on external server because the requests that are sent through my flask routes, have to be sent from the ip of the user, and not the ip of the server.

Comment: @Thomas can you help please ?